# Ubuntu 14.04 ssh server hanging when connecting but pings works

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, sshd

I am running an Ubuntu ssh server with login and ChallengeResponseAuthentication enabled.
However, the following command outputs this and hangs until timing out:

```
ssh -vvv name@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
```

When I try to ping the server address, the server responds.
Except for the two changes mentioned above, the sshd_config file is the same as the default Ubuntu 14.04 file.

What steps should I take next to debug this?

Update:
`sudo iptables -S` prints the following:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

The network should support SSH (another computer hooked into the network the same at this one (but running CentOS) can be ssh'd into no problem.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall? I believe that Ubuntu 14.04 uses `iptables` as it's firewall software. Could you provide the output of `sudo iptables -S`?
Also, it could be that an upstream device from the server is blocking SSH, what is the network like between you and the server?

Comment: @prateek61 thanks for the reply. Updated with info